# Gpick not working arch linux

Tags: arch-linux

I tried gpick,gcolor2,gcolor3 and another one,All of these doesn't work in arch.In gpick icon of application goes on repeating every second in pick area,pressing space key it picks only black color.Any help with gpick or other working color picker.

Comment: I use gcolor2 on my Arch installation and it works pretty flawlessly. Elaborate on your problem with gcolor2 please.

Comment: I'm not able to pick color with it.When I click on color picker icon it appears on screen but when i press space or mouse click only black color comes in palette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are running wayland, if you start your desktop environment using Xorg then gpick should work.

I had the same issue in gnome, changing to Gnome with Xorg before logging in made gpick work again.

Answer (score 0):

By default `gpick` does not add picked color to the palette. This behavior can be changed in settings.

Go to `Edit` -> `Settings` -> `Picker` tab, and make sure that *Add to palette* is checked in section *Floating picker click behaviour* (and optionally, in *'Spacebar' button behaviour*):

[image: Gpick settings]

Comment: Yeah It's selected already,add to palette for both the options but problem is one image is being repeated every second 3-4 times in picking area,so not able to pick color.shown in this [Image](https://l51i.imgup.net/gpicke198.jpg)